# Resize the height of the header in QTableWidget in PyQt

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5

I am trying to include a `QTableWidget` in my app with four columns and I need the columns in the header to `stretch` according to the window size. Currently, the columns occupy only a certain width and doesn't stretch to the window.

Here is a minimum verifiable example of my problem:

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets

class MyTable(QtWidgets.QTableWidget):
    def __init__(self, *args):
        QtWidgets.QTableWidget.__init__(self, *args)
        self.setheader()
        self.resizeColumnsToContents()
        self.resizeRowsToContents()

    def setheader(self):
        self.setHorizontalHeaderLabels(['Label 1', 'Label 2', 'Label 3'])    

def main(args):
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(args)
    table = MyTable(5, 3)
    table.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main(sys.argv)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are re-implementing a `QTableWidget` this is the instruction you need to give to achieve the stretch effect:

```
self.horizontalHeader().setSectionResizeMode(QtWidgets.QHeaderView.Stretch)
```

You call the `QHeaderView` from the `QTableWidget` and give it the `Stretch` instruction. The following example is a working implementation of this:

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets

class MyTable(QtWidgets.QTableWidget):
    def __init__(self, *args):
        QtWidgets.QTableWidget.__init__(self, *args)
        self.setheader()
        self.resizeColumnsToContents()
        self.resizeRowsToContents()

    def setheader(self):
        self.setHorizontalHeaderLabels(['Label 1', 'Label 2', 'Label 3'])
        self.horizontalHeader().setSectionResizeMode(QtWidgets.QHeaderView.Stretch)
        #self.horizontalHeader().setStretchLastSection(True) # This is another possible option


def main(args):
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(args)
    table = MyTable(5, 3)
    table.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main(sys.argv)
```

, which results in this:

[image: QTableWidget with stretching header - part 1]

[image: QTableWidget with stretching header - part 2]

In the code example above there is another possibility that will give you the same objective with a different style. It's commented but should you use it (instead of the first instruction):

```
self.horizontalHeader().setStretchLastSection(True)
```

, and only the last column will stretch:

[image: QTableWidget with stretching header - part 3]

Comment: I have used the setSectionResizeMode. Works like a charm. But what I now need is the column width to size according to the cell's contents. Although I have used resizeCoulmnToContents() and resizeRowsToContents, that doesn't work

Comment: @North This question has just been branded as off-topic (although, from my point of view, it isn't) and it seems both question and answer got some kind of "revenge" downvoting. I think you should formulate another question to your new problem. Try putting a Minimal Verifiable Example (Its common for questions to be branded off-topic when they are considered low quality) . Feel free to use the code in my answer. I'll edit this question to contain a minimum verifiable example (because it is a relevant question). If this is not OK with you feel free to re-edit it again or revert my changes.